# Database does not exist error

Tags: c#, sql-server

When I take a database backup I get an error that the database does not exist, but I can attach the database fine and other processes like data insert and update work fine. But when I take a database backup it gives the error below.

I show the error screen shot and the backup button code

```
string cnstr="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\fees_data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;"



SqlConnection connect;
        connect = new SqlConnection(cnstr);
        connect.Open();
        if (txtdname.Text == "")
        { dname = "Default.bak"; }
        else
        { dname = txtdname.Text + ".bak"; }
        SqlCommand command;
        command = new SqlCommand(@"backup database fees_data to disk ='c:\DATABackup\" + dname + "'", connect);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connect.Close();
```

When I click the backup button I get the error:

> "Database 'fees_data' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.
>   BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally."

Comment: this will work in this you just conform the Database name and path not any code mistake just check your DataBase name and Path where you store your backup file...

Answer (score 3):

The database name might not be the same as the .mdf file name.

What results do you get when running this query ?

```
select name from sys.databases;
```

Use the correct name from there.

Answer (score 1):

instead of this code

```
SqlCommand command;
   command = new SqlCommand(@"backup database fees_data to disk ='c:\DATABackup\" + dname + "'", connect);
   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

use code written below

```
string fullPath= "";
 string executable = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
 fullPath= (System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(executable));
 AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", fullPath);
 fullPath=fullPath+"\\fees_data.mdf";

 SqlCommand command;
 command = new SqlCommand(@"backup ['"+fullPath+"'] to disk ='c:\DATABackup\" + dname + "'", connect);
 command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```