# database not found after publish

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, sqlcommand

I make one project with sql database and it works without any error in visual studio 2012 but after publish and install it, when I take backup it shows below error

> "Database 'C:\Users\LU\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\D9HBHD8T.Y1H\5B2JMG1T.N8W\game..tion_60f48512c0fd7b6a_0001.0000_7a5b2d8ced8c74c0\gamedata.mdf' does not exist. Make sure that the name is
>   entered correctly. BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally."

Here is my procedure

```
CREATE proc dbackup
@databaseName sysname,
@path nvarchar(400)
as
backup database @databaseName to disk = @path with init
return
```

Here is my backup code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  DataBase db=new DataBase();
  try
  {
    db.connect();
    SqlCommand oCommand = new SqlCommand(@"dbackup",db.sqlcon);
    oCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@databaseName", Application.StartupPath + "\\gamedata.mdf");
    oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@path", textBox1.Text);
    oCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Backup Created Sucessfully");
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Error Occurd :" + ex.Message);
  }
  finally
  {
    db.disconnect();
  }
  this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Is your `dbackup` procedure in the database 'fees_data'?

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588165/database-does-not-exist-error. Even has the same database name...

Comment: example fees_data my data base name is gamedata.mdf

Comment: Show your connection string. What is your SQL Server edition used on development and in production?

Comment: Why do you not publish exact text of your exception instead of some sample? The exception would be something like `Database 'c:\...\gamedata.mdf'  does not ...`

Comment: i use visual studio for make data base

Comment: my First time in site and not know how to Properly ask

Comment: Just instead of an example enter exactly the text that appears in the MessageBox after `Error Occurd :` - the exact ex.Message text.

Comment: ok now if u know answer it and i see up link i cant use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `Application.StartupPath` to store your database if you are deploying your app with ClickOnce.

It seems that you are using LocalDB edition of SQL Server. There you use correctly the full name of your file as a parameter for `backup database` command.

But the name of ClickOnce installation folder is obfuscated, so it will not work in SQL statement.

You must copy the `.mdf` file from your installation folder to some other local folder when your application is first launched after installation and use that folder for your data.